# Why isn't Lit calculating my background color within Web Components?

Tags: web-component, lit

I have some very basic code like this

```js
#component file
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
import sheet from './css/styles.js';

export class CaiWc extends LitElement {
  static styles = [sheet];

  render() {
    return html`
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
      <div>ITEM 1</div>
      <div>ITEM 2</div>
      <div>ITEM 3</div>
    `;
  }
}
```

```js
#styles.js
import { css } from 'lit';

export default css`
  :root {
    background-color: #0000cc;
    color: #ff0000;
  }

  :host {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #0000cc;
  }
`;
```

I don't understand why no background colors are showing up. When my markup was more complex with a third party web component, that web component would have the background color set from `:host`. If I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color correctly, background color isn't inherited. However if the default is transparent, why isn't it filling in?

[image: chrome inspector showing a web component taking space with a set background color, yet not background color is used. the font color works as expected]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the custom element host defaults to `display: inline` - which results in the `background-color` not showing up. Additionally setting width and height would have no effect.

Adding `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your `:host` styles should fix the issue, recommended by these [Custom Element Best Practices](https://web.dev/custom-elements-best-practices/#:%7E:text=Set%20a%20%3Ahost%20display%20style%20(e.g.%20block%2C%20inline%2Dblock%2C%20flex)%20unless%20you%20prefer%20the%20default%20of%20inline.).

There is also some discussion around this behavior in this Github issue: [Should shadow host have `display: block` by default](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/426).
And followup discussion around resolving this issue: [Provide a lightweight mechanism to add styles to a custom element](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/468).

Comment: Thanks, Chrome inspector showing the whole area lit up misled me a bit. Would have never guessed about the inline thing and didn't see anything about it with my Google search!